# Static variable inside spark job -Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am having some issue with spark and static variables. I have a configuration class with some static variables which I am initializing from a property file at runtime.

```
        System.out.println("Outside : "+ActiveMQConfig.HOST_ADDRESS);
        rePartition.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
            public Void call ( JavaRDD<String> rdd ) throws Exception
            {
                rdd.map(new Function<String, String>() {
                    public String call ( String line ) throws Exception
                    {
                        System.out.println("Inside :" + ActiveMQConfig.HOST_ADDRESS);
                        return null;
                    }
                }).count();
                return null;
            }
        });
        ssc.remember(new Duration(1 * 60 * 1000));
        ssc.start();
```

The default value for `ActiveMQConfig.HOST_ADDRESS` is `localhost` and I am setting some IP from property file at runtime.

The first system out prints the ip `Outside : ip` but the system out inside map method prints the default value `Inside :localhost`. What I am doing wrong here? do I need to broadcast all the variables which I want to use inside spark? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a not-so-helpful answer: is it possible to avoid "static" in your code? Very often people think that introducing global state via static is a good idea; but very often ... it is not really required; and causing problems in the long run.

Comment: @Jägermeister Sorry I cant make config variable a non static variable as I am initializing these variables once and using at different parts of the application.

Comment: are passing the property file with the --files option using spark-submit?

Comment: @urug no I am not..the file is inside the jar file which I am submitting to spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with object initialization in the JVM.
Each worker will load and initialize the class holding the static variable, but probably (not shown in question) only the driver is initializing the value of such variable on the VM of the driver.

The result is that the driver has the updated value, but each executor has the default value.

One way of working around this is to provide the value explicitly to the closure:

```
rePartition.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
     String host = ActiveMQConfig.HOST_ADDRESS 
     ...
          System.out.println("Inside :" + host)
     ...
}
```